Can't import TensorFlow in Jupyter lab
I'm trying import TensorFlow into Jupyter lab. I tried the following command in the Jupyter notebook:
%pip install tensflow

I was met with the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Apparently tensorflow only works with python 3.9 to python 3.12. My computer has 3.13 installed, so I download python 3.12 and try again without success.I open up a new terminal window and use the following command"
pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/versions/2.18.0/tensorflow-2.18.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl

TensorFlow seems to install without issue. I can even see with pip3 list command in terminal.
When I go back to Jupyter lab, I can't use an import statement to get TensorFlow, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'. Running %pip list does not show TensorFlow. I don't know what to do...
